# Conditions satisfied for over determined system to be consistent

Tags: linear-algebra

The original equations is here. I know I need to solve for b1, b2, b3, b4, b5
So I do row operations to reduce the matrix

x1-3x2 = b1
x1-2x2 = b2
x1+x2 = b3
x1-4x2 = b4
x1+5x2 = b5

The part I don't understand is why are the b1 values changing from this step

1 -3 b1
0 1 b2-b1
0 4 b3-b1
0 -1 b4-b1
0 8 b5 - b1

to this step

1 -3 b1
0 1 b2-b1
0 0 b3-4b2+3b1
0 0 b4+b2-2b1
0 0 b5-8b2+7b1

It doesn't make any sense to me why b1 should change. I've already applied -b1 to every row to get all 0's in the first column. Why does applying b2 operations to get 0's in the second column affect my initial b1 operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that you are adding $-4R_2$ ($-4$ times Row 2) to $R_3$. Since the right hand column in $R_2$ is $b_2-b_1$, we're actually adding $-4b_2+4b_1$ to the right hand column of $R_3$.

Comment: wow. That was so easy, I can't believe I didn't notice that. Thanks!